# Python cleanest way to parse

Tags: python

A have a several log lines of the form `"TimeA:0.216/1,TimeB:495.761/1,TimeC:2.048/2,TimeD:0.296/1"`(syntax is timerName:time/instances)` and this is how I am parsing it

```
ServiceTimer = namedtuple("ServiceTimer", ["timerName", "time", "instances"])
timers = []
for entry in line.split(","):
    name, rest = entry.split(":")
    time, instances = rest.split("/")
    timers.append(ServiceTimer(name, float(time), int(instances)))
```

Is there a better way of doing it, it also needs to be fast since there are millions of log lines. Any pointers would be great.

Comment: Do you need to use `namedtuple`?

Comment: use regular expression groups?  http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html If you were using Perl , you can process this much faster

Comment: @allKid, not necessarily, I was wondering if using dictionaries would be faster.

Answer (score 2):

I tested three versions:

- Your original code without the named tuple.
- The regexp example with type conversion.
- Another regexp version with a couple speed tricks.

The results kinda surprised me. My results show that "string".split is really fast, faster than the example regexp processing. In order to make the regexp faster, you have to use a memory mapped file and forget the line-by-line processing.

Here's the source in temp.py:

```
def process1():
    results = []
    with open('temp.txt') as fptr:
        for line in fptr:
            for entry in line.split(','):
                name, rest = entry.split(":")
                time, instances = rest.split("/")
                results.append((name, float(time), int(instances)))
    return len(results)

def process2():
    from re import finditer
    results = []
    with open('temp.txt') as fptr:
        for line in fptr:
            for match in finditer(r'([^,:]*):([^/]*)/([^,]*)', line):
                results.append(
                    (match.group(1), float(match.group(2)), int(match.group(3))))
    return len(results)

def process3():
    from re import finditer
    import mmap
    results = []
    with open('temp.txt', 'r+') as fptr:
        fmap = mmap.mmap(fptr.fileno(), 0)
        for match in finditer(r'([^,:]*):([^/]*)/([^,\r\n]*)', fmap):
            results.append(
                (match.group(1), float(match.group(2)), int(match.group(3))))
    return len(results)
```

I tested these functions on a "temp.txt" text file with a million duplicates of your example line. Here's the results:

```
In [8]: %time temp.process1()
CPU times: user 10.24 s, sys: 0.00 s, total: 10.24 s
Wall time: 10.24 s
Out[8]: 4000000

In [9]: %time temp.process2()
CPU times: user 12.63 s, sys: 0.00 s, total: 12.63 s
Wall time: 12.63 s
Out[9]: 4000000

In [10]: %time temp.process3()
CPU times: user 9.43 s, sys: 0.00 s, total: 9.43 s
Wall time: 9.43 s
Out[10]: 4000000
```

So the regexp version that ignores line-by-line processing and memory-maps the file is 7% faster than your example code. The example regexp code is 23% slower than your example.

Moral of the story: always benchmark.

Comment: another moral of the story - you can't improve what you don't measure.

Comment: if speed is a concern, i think list comprehension is faster than `append`. see my edits

Comment: I created a "process4" function based on your list comprehension and measured locally. As compared with "process2" it was ~2% faster. But that measurement is within the observed noise. The slow factor in your example @runnerup is the line-by-line parsing. You may note in "process3" that I modified your regexp slightly to not match across lines, that's what I believe created the speedup.

Comment: @runnerup, also the regexp pattern is automatically compiled by the library and that compilation is cached. You might be saving a tiny bit of performance by passing in the compiled regexp but you're only avoiding a dictionary lookup. Measured locally, pre-compiling the regexp was actually a couple percent slower although that measurement was still within the obersved noise.

Answer (score 1):

per @zaftcoAgeiha suggestion, using regex:

```
from re import finditer
line = "TimeA:0.216/1,TimeB:495.761/1,TimeC:2.048/2,TimeD:0.296/1"
[ m.groups( ) for m in finditer( r'([^,:]*):([^/]*)/([^,]*)', line ) ]
```

you will get:

```
[('TimeA', '0.216', '1'),
 ('TimeB', '495.761', '1'),
 ('TimeC', '2.048', '2'),
 ('TimeD', '0.296', '1')]
```

for type casting you may use `group` method:

```
[ ( m.group(1), float( m.group(2) ) , int( m.group(3) ))
    for m in finditer( r'([^,:]*):([^/]*)/([^,]*)', line ) ]
```

**edit**: to parse the whole file you need to compile the pattern first and use list comprehension instead of `append`:

```
from re import compile

regex = compile( r'([^,:]*):([^/]*)/([^,]*)' )
with open( 'fname.txt', 'r' ) as fin:
    results = [ ( m.group(1), float( m.group(2) ) , int( m.group(3) ))
        for m in regex.finditer( line ) for line in fin]
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe with less lines..

```
  for entry in line.split(','):
    split_line = entry.split(":")[1].split('/')
    timers.append(ServiceTimer(entry.split(':')[0],float(split_line[0]),int(split_line[1])
```